# Tkinter i want to add a background image and want to display widgets on top of that , but widgets hiding behind the image

Tags: python, tkinter

the arc is hiding behind the image
and i want to display it above the image
and how to add more images which overlay on he background image

```
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange
from tkinter import Tk , Canvas , messagebox , font
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

canvasw = 1200
canvash = 800

win = Tk()

c = Canvas(win, bg="blue", height=canvash, width=canvasw)
backg = PhotoImage(file = "back.png")
background_label = Label(win, image=backg)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

eg = PhotoImage(file = "eg.png")
ep = PhotoImage(file = "ep.png")
er = PhotoImage(file = "er.png")
ey = PhotoImage(file = "ey.png")


ew = 45
eh = 55
es = 10

ev = 500
ei = 4000
dfcl = 0.95
catchcol = 'black'
catw = 100
cath = 100
catsx1 = canvasw / 2 - catw /2
catsy1 = canvash - cath -20
catsx2 = catsx1 + catw 
catsy2 = catsy1 + cath
cat = c.create_arc(catsx1,catsy1,catsx2,catsy2, start= 200 ,extent = 140, style='arc', outline=catchcol, width=3) 

c.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

the arc is hiding behind the image
and i want to display it above the image

Answer (score 0):

`relwidth=1, relheight=1`  is causing the the arc not be shown

so do

```
background_label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

`relwidth=1, relheight=1` sets the label to be as big as the window, so the label will cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `create_image()` to put the background image into canvas instead of using label:

```py
c.create_image(0, 0, image=backg, anchor='nw')
```

---

Note that you should avoid importing modules as below:

```py
from tkinter import Tk , Canvas , messagebox , font
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

The first import is override by the second import, so the first import is not necessary.  Also some of the widgets in `tkinter` will be override by the third import, i.e widgets from `ttk`.

You should import the modules as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```